# Is there any reason not to play support Maokai in Season 6?

Tags: league-of-legends

In season 3, I played Maokai as a support, and found that this was not a bad idea.
Generally it only works well when the enemy ADC was a "poke" type (e.g. Ezreal or Corki). Maokai's passive gives him a lot of sustain, he has some poke, a slow, damage reduction, and a snare.

But is there any reason not to play him as support now? Players criticize me for picking a "troll" pick although I see great potential in him.  What makes him different from other supports?

Comment: You seem to have outlined exactly the reasons someone might want to play this role. If you're asking whether it's viable in the current meta, that's a very different question--and one for which answers will mostly be opinion-based.

Comment: So is there any reason to people call me troll when I try to play it? I believe that mao can be a good choice but this might be only my opinion that is why I ask this question I am not a professional player so it will be nice to hear opinion someone more experienced

Comment: @Aht I tried editting your question to what it sounds like you're trying to say. Let me know if thats not what you wanted :)

Comment: @hammythepig that Is exactly what I want to ask. Thanks for that edit my English is not the best and fact that I write from mobile make it even more complicate :)

Comment: because you can't do the job of a support with maokai, if you want to do this I suggest finding a friend to go ADC so that they can adopt a play style that would better suit a maokai support. "troll" support picks work fantastic if you can synergize with the adc, 99.999% of the time it means you'll need to play bot with a friend

Comment: @Aequitas Trundle and Poppy are meta support picks right now for their solid ability to catch enemies out of position and peel for allies--both things that Maokai excels at. So arguing that Maokai can't do the job of a support and calling it a troll pick seems more like a reactionary defense of the meta quo (not even that, given the current meta) than an actual expanation.

Comment: @AverageUnknown trundle and poppy both have far better cc than maokai has

Comment: @Aequitas CC is not the only utility that's valid for a support. Maokai can get long range vision with his E (in a season where safe vision is hard to come by) and blocks damage with his ult. It also depends on your definition of "better": Trundle has two slows, a knockup if he aims well, and a "wall", while maokai has two slows, a knockup in the right positioning, and a point-and-click root that puts him in the middle of the fight. Is one of those kits objectively better than the other? (This conversation is why I figured this would be closed for opinion-based, but someone seems to disagree.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with Maokai support. He has a number of very useful skills as a support, but there may be situations in which another support may be better. For instance depending on the adc, another support may synergize better, for instance Kalista and Tahm Kench synergize very well together. Another reason could be that the another champion may fit the team composition better, such as Janna if you need good disengage. So really it just comes down to whether or not you can play him well, and if it fits well with your team. The reason people are calling you a troll is most likely due to the fact that many people feel that whenever someone plays an off-meta pick, they think they are trolling, even if it can work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current meta, the support role is someone who can peel for his team while still being impactfull on the enemy team.

Commonly played Supports on LCS:

Allistar : Why? Huge CC kit, can easily act has an engage or disengage and can also act has a huge Frontline for your team while simultaneously peeling

Morgana : Completely negates Pick comps, can allow your team to perform a pick, due to her Ult you can stop the enemy frontline from diving your backline

Braum : Same as Allistar pretty much but provides a Wall that blocks pretty much everything thrown at it, used properly can turn around a teamfight

Where does Maokai fit in all of this? Yes he has a good kit with sustain and Poke, but he falls of pretty quick if you don't itemise tank items, and in a teamfight he won't be diving the enemy backline probably, not that it's a bad pick, just not viable, if you get paired vs 2 ranged you won't do much cuz you can't freely engage or go for trades, while it might be a solid pick since it can provide the *required by meta* engage/disengage , there are more solid picks for support that better complemente this, for instance if you pair the Maokai vs Ez and Morg he is gonna be useless in the laning phase since the morgana shield will deny him of any engage opportunity and Ez can just E away

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the meta

Maokai isn't a popular support hero, and not played much at all

so when you do pick him it seems like a troll pick

**In my honest opinion -** if YOU play Maokai well and YOU think he does well as a support - DO IT, ignore people in chat and prove them wrong!